# How can i Search multiple files one pattern and return the matched values from the latest file?

Tags: perl

I am totally new to perl programming. Please help me to form a logic for this.

I have many files in one directory, e.g. `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, ..., `n.txt`.

Each file contains several data in this format. The ID column will be unique along a file.

```
ID | Name  | Place   

1  | name1 | Chennai

2  | name2 | Mumbai
```

There can be change the ID -1 can repeat in different file. So I need to search each ID in all the files in the directory and write the attributes for each ID to another file. The resultant file should have unique ID's and the attributes should be from the file with latest creation date.

So BASICALLY resulting file will be a master list of ID's and the attributes.

Please help in this regard. I am only  able to read the file and select it and put it in a different file. Could anyone  please help me to move forward on this.

Thank you so much in Advance

Comment: Is Perl the only tool you can use?

Answer (score 3):

Use a hash with IDs as keys and store the values from the files in timestamp order in that hash.
Here's a prototype:

```
my %data;

for my $file (sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @files) {
    my @data = process_file($file); # an array of hashrefs like { id => 1, name => "name1", place => 'Chennai' }
    $data{$_->{id}} = $_ for @data;        
}
```

Then store the data from the hash to a file.

Comment: How does that ensure that the value of the ID from the latest file (i.e. most recent timestamp) takes precedence?

Comment: Really though all you need is one hash - store the values from the files in timestamp order in that hash and the final result will be as required. Then just dump out the resulting hash. No need to store all the values for each ID.